# How can I access a data file from a Unit test method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Here is how I am trying to access the file-

1. I added a folder "TestData" in my unit test project
2. Added a file via Add->Existing Item. Set the Build Action=None, Copy To Output Directory= Copy Always

Accessing the file in the unit test method as below-

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(
            System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "TestData\\TestExcel2007File1.xlsx");

XmlDocument actual;
actual.Load(fileName);       //Throws exception saying cannot find part of the file path
```

I also tried using the Method attribute as-

```
[TestMethod, DeploymentItem(@"Test Data\", @"Test Data\")]
```

None seems to work.

The file path generated is

```
"D:\\MyProject\\TestResults\\MACHINE_NAME 2015-01-23 05_21_45\\Out\\TestData\\TestExcel2007File1.xlsx"
```

And the Out folder does not have the **TestData** folder, or the Excel file.

**EDIT**: My referenced assemblies are present in the Out folder. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

I did the same steps in a different project in Visual Studio 2012 and that seem to find the file in place and work as expected.

**EDIT 2**: I found that the TestData folder is copied in ***bin\debug*** folder, not in the path generated. But the referenced assemblies are copied in the generated path!

**EDIT 3**: Added a testsetting file and checked the Enable Deployment Menu, added the TestData folder in the Additional Files and directory to deploy list, still didn't work.

Comment: Just a note: unit tests shouldn't touch any external resources (files, databases etc.). If you need to test some functionality in unit test, you need to mock these out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting the visual studio made it work. Not even closing and reopening the solution was enough!!!

Answer (score 3):

I work with xUnit and do it this way:

```
public static string GetImportPath()
{
    string[] importPaths =
    {
            @"TestData", @"..\TestData", @"..\..\TestData",
    };
    string importPath = importPaths.FirstOrDefault(Directory.Exists);
    Guard.NotNull(importPath, "importPath not found");
    return importPath;
}
```

I have the folder `TestData` in my Project folder, same level as `bin`, `Properties` etc.

In your case you'd use it like this:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(GetImportPath(), "TestExcel2007File1.xlsx");
```

Comment: thanks, but Linq or Guard class is not available for my tests!

Comment: Well, you can omit this Guard, its just a safety check, not important